# Bootstrap Only open one modal at a time?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'd like to use the modal feature in Bootstrap to display images.

I have 4 different images and I noticed after my second image when I open it and the modal appears, it opens the first one too.

Is there a way to only open one modal at a time as opposed to every one on the page?

Here's the code I am using (I've already tried putting them in separated containers as I've read works, but still no luck)

```html
<div id="gallerydrawings">
<h2 class="text-plan">Plans</h2>
 <ul>
  <li>
   <img class="modalimg" data-toggle="modal" height="60" width="120" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" src="images/smestowff3d.png" title="Smestow First Floor Plan" style="cursor:pointer">
   <div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
     <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Smestow High School | First floor plan</h4>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
<img src="images/smestowff3d.png" class="modalimg" style="height: auto; max-width:100%; float:center;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</li>

<li>
<img class="modalimg" data-toggle="modal" height="60" width="120" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" src="images/smestowfflayout.png" title="Smestow First Floow Plan" style="cursor:pointer">
<div class="modal fade bs-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">X</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel">Smestow High School | First floor plan</h4>
        </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
<img src="images/smestowfflayout.png" class="modalimg" style="height: auto; max-width:100%; float:center;">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try by using different id's for different modal

Answer (score 0):

Notice the

- **data-target=".bleak-modal-lg14"**
  Assign a new target name for each modal
- **aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel-14"**
  Assign a new target name for each modal
- **id="myLargeModalLabel-14"**
  keep this ID the same as your aria-labelledby value.

You also want to add that data-target name in the same class tag as your "modal fade". The below is a sample I took from one of my old projects.

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bleak-modal-lg14">
<img src="img14_thumb.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="" width="570" height="144">
</a>


<div class="modal fade bleak-modal-lg14" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel-14" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
<div class="modal-content">
 <div class="modal-header" style="background-color: black;">
 <h5 class="modal-title words" id="myLargeModalLabel-14" style="background-color: black;">title
 </h5>
 <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">
 <span aria-hidden="true" style="color: white;">&times; 
 </span>
 </button>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-body" style="background-color: black;">
 <img src="img14.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="">
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="modal-footer words"><div style="background: black;">(c) 2003-2017 blank. All rights reserved.   |  See this image in  <a href="img14.jpg" target="new"><strong>FULL SIZE</strong></a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```